# How effective was medieval horse armor?

Tags: middle-ages, cavalry, armour

Medieval longbows seem now to have been only marginally effective against armoured knights of early fifteenth century although Henry Fifth was wounded in the face at Shrewsbury in 1403 with a limited penetration possibly caused by an arrow through the breathing holes of a bascinet. He still chose mostly archers for his army 12 years later so he must have had good reason to do so even if his own injury was relatively unlucky.
Was this the vulnerabilty of the horses ? or the multi-role fighting modes the archers were capable of. Is there any evidence of horse casualty rates?
At Poitiers the French chose to attack dismounted and in several battles the archers were seemingly arraigned to effect arrow storms into the sides of the attack. was this more effective on horses or riders ?

Comment: I suspect the real answer is that we don't know. Modern arms and armour testing seems to be at odds with the historic accounts of medieval battles with regard to longbow effectiveness.

Comment: Note that the arrow didn't need to penetrate to be effective. The impact alone would delay, bruise and batter the target. That's enough to (potentially) produce crushing results once the melee is joined.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.